# Как корректно обновить значение в ConcurrentHashMap в многопоточной среде

Tags: java, concurrency

У меня есть довольно простой класс, который собирает статистику по статусам.

```
public class Status {
    private ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> statusesMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void addStatus(String status) {
        if (statusesMap.containsKey(status)) {
            statusesMap.get(status).getAndIncrement();
        } else {
            statusesMap.put(status, new AtomicInteger(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Очевидно, что при обращении к методу addStatus из нескольких потоков в результате в мапе будет неверное значение. Делать полностью метод синхронным не хотелось бы - это лишняя нагрузка. Можно ли код как-то преобразовать? Например на writeReadLock?

---

Попробовала и `computeIfAbsent` и `compute`.  Но метод `computeIfAbsent`, судя по всему, имеет  [проблему](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161372) с блокировками для java8. У `compute` наблюдала аналогичное поведение. Пока решением видится

```
   AtomicLong result = statusesMap.get(status);
   if (result != null) {
         result.getAndIncrement();
   } else {
         statusesMap.computeIfAbsent(status, t -> new AtomicLong()).getAndIncrement();
   }
```

Comment: А разве все действие в этом методе не атомарно? Думаю, этот метод должен быть synchronized. Не вижу мест, которые можно оставить несинхронизированными.

Comment: @Miron а если попробовать переписать код так ? `public void addStatus(String status) {
        AtomicInteger result = statusesMap.computeIfAbsent(status, t->new AtomicInteger(0));
        result.getAndIncrement();
    }`

Comment: Поглядите метод [compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html)